# Error drawing a large number of values from the normal distribution

Tags: fortran

I have to fill a large array of size (150000,35) with random numbers drawn from the normal distribution. I am using r8mat_normal_ab from the r8lib library (https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/f_src/r8lib/r8lib.html and https://pastebin.com/0pEkZfYp); for some reason, a segmentation fault occurs if the size of the first dimension of the array is greater than about 27,000. I am using the intel compiler. This is the failing code

```
program test2
    integer, parameter :: dp=kind(0.d0)
    integer, parameter :: n_sim = 30000
    integer, parameter :: nt = 35
    real(dp) :: shockARWmat(n_sim,nt+1)
    real(dp) :: sigmaARW=sqrt(.0344705)
    integer :: seed_sim=234567, i

    call r8mat_normal_ab (n_sim, nt+1, 0., sigmaARW, seed_sim, shockARWmat)

    print*, 'success !!'

end program
```

While if I set `n_sim = 27000` or lower it works fine. Is there a compilation parameter I am missing when I am dealing with large matrices? Setting `-mcmodel=large` did not help.

Comment: Have you checked the stack size limit? If you are using Linux, try `ulimit -s unlimited` then run the program. If you are in Windows you are out of luck unless you specify heap memoery allocation for your program by the compiler. See for example `heap_arrays` flag of intel compiler.

Comment: I am on a docker container running Debian, I think (I just pulled the ifort image from intel). If I run ```ulimit -s unlimited``` it does not produce any output

Comment: The command does not output anything. It merely sets the stack limit to unlimited. Then run your program. Stack size limit is a common cause of `segfault` errors, when the programs storage requirements are significant.

Comment: yep that seems to work! thanks if you submit the answer I'll approve it

Comment: Better would be to make the `shockARWmat` allocatable, does that fix it?

Comment: The library which you point to does not contain a function r8mat_normal_ab . It has r8_normal_ab, and r8vec_normal_ab but not that one. Could you provide the source for that function, please? I am guess it is just the two dimensional version of the previous 2, but to make sure we are looking at the same thing it would be by far best if you can provide what you have.

Comment: Yes, the code of that subroutine would really be helpful. I expect it probably uses some automatic array that becomes too large.

Comment: Sorry, here is the missing code https://pastebin.com/0pEkZfYp